# How to find if image rotated or mirrored by using letter 'F'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to test multiple cameras. -One camera per test- So if cameras stream inverted or mirrored image I want to log them.
**Target has letter 'F' on Cartesian plane for testing purpose.**

TARGET:

[image: TARGET]

mirrored vertically, horizontally:

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

I use opencv (4.6.0) and python (3.8). I searched google but couldn't find any result that i can understand. I'm a newbie at this topic. So if you give me a hint that would be awesome.

Thank you for your time.

Update#1: Cameras are all same. And all will be in the same position but it can be some mistakes wile placing it. I want to know is anything wrong with the cameras itself. I have other test for placing the camera. And targets are not from camera. I draw them with paint. I cant share the real target because I don't think i have rights to share.

UPDATE#2: I convince customer to accept Aruco. I can do  it now with arucos positions. Thanx for help everyone. I will share the method If I can manage to get some time for myself.

Comment: all cameras have the same scope ? how can it be possible ? TARGET you referred belongs to a camera view ? and other image views have the different camera views ?

Comment: Cut the image into 4 equal regions, shave a few edge pixels to get rid of dividing lines, threshold, take the region with lowest mean.

Comment: if you have a reference frame, just create from your query image a mirrored, a rotated and a mirrored+rotated version (or more general for each combination of rotation (e.g. multiple 90° steps?) and mirror (horizontal/vertical/both)) and test them against your query image. There should be only one that matches your reference image (best).

Comment: @Micka Can you give me the name of the method or link for the topic?

Comment: Check: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html ! This requires that the template you are searching is of the same resolution (pixel hight and width) as contained in the image.

Comment: instead of an ad-hoc pattern, I'd recommend showing an aruco or other AR marker. maybe even a QR code, if your decoder library can tell you its orientation. for flips, just try decoding a flipped-back image. detection is invariant to rotation already, so the entire thing should cost you one flip and two detections.